# How to make a temporary table of this query? (Multiple joins)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

for a project I created this query which shows data from the Employee, Client, Party, District, Canton, Province and General_Telephone2 tables using multiple joins, however now I need to save and show the result of that query in a temp table named Query1, How do I do this?

I tried:
(SELECT * INTO newtable FROM oldtable) But I don't know what the oldtable is, because is a query with joins

```
SELECT E.EmpleadoID, E.Salario, E.Horario, P.Nombre + P-PrimerApellido + P.SegundoApellido AS 'Nombre Completo', Pr.Nombre
AS 'Provincia', Ca.Nombre AS 'Canton', D.Nombre AS 'Distrito', T.Telefono
FROM EMPLEADO E
INNER JOIN CLIENTE C
ON  E.ClienteID = C.ClienteID
INNER JOIN Party P
ON P.NumCedula = C.NumCedula
INNER JOIN Distrito D
ON D.IdDistrito = P.IdDistrito
INNER JOIN Canton Ca
ON Ca.IdCanton = D.IdCanton
INNER JOIN Provincia Pr
ON Pr.IdProvincia = Ca.IdProvinca
INNER JOIN Telefonos_General_V2 T
ON T.Cedula = P.NumCedula
ORDER BY EmpleadoID
```

I need a way to save the result of the query in a temporary table

Answer (score 1):

You just need a # in temporary table name.

```
SELECT * 
INTO #Query1
FROM oldtable
```

OR This with your query i have insert it to temporary table.

```
SELECT E.EmpleadoID, E.Salario, E.Horario, P.Nombre + P-PrimerApellido + P.SegundoApellido AS 'Nombre Completo', Pr.Nombre
AS 'Provincia', Ca.Nombre AS 'Canton', D.Nombre AS 'Distrito', T.Telefono
INTO #TemporaryTable1
FROM EMPLEADO E
INNER JOIN CLIENTE C
ON  E.ClienteID = C.ClienteID
INNER JOIN Party P
ON P.NumCedula = C.NumCedula
INNER JOIN Distrito D
ON D.IdDistrito = P.IdDistrito
INNER JOIN Canton Ca
ON Ca.IdCanton = D.IdCanton
INNER JOIN Provincia Pr
ON Pr.IdProvincia = Ca.IdProvinca
INNER JOIN Telefonos_General_V2 T
ON T.Cedula = P.NumCedula
ORDER BY EmpleadoID
```

Comment: Yes but in this case, oldtable are many tables due to multiple join so...idk what to write there

Comment: This way you can save the result of your query to a temporary table.